# Synology root truecrypt over ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, truecrypt, root

I can not find the syntax to mount a remote volume with truecrypt / ssh .

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh /id_rsa root@192.168.0.107 'truecrypt /home/rep.tc/home/dossier'
```

but not work.....

```
--------          SSH             ---------------------------
Synology =========================  Fedora serveur (truecrypt)
--------                          ---------------------------
```

i want create a bash script on synology for :

```
truecrypt : mount remote volume (fedora) 
rsync : this part it's ok 
truecrypt : dismount remote volume (fedora)
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is a truecrypt file container you could mount the folder via sshfs and then use truecrypt to mount the file-container into another folder

```
sshfs remote-server.de:/home/srvadmin/daten /media/verzeichnisname
truecrypt /media/verzeichnisname/truecryptcontainerfile /Pfad/zum/Einhängepunkt
```